# How to change markdown style for github pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, kramdown

If I wanted to use a specific github page theme, such as [cayman](https://github.com/pages-themes/cayman), but wanted my markdown to look and be styled differently, say to be styled like the [architect theme markdown](https://pages-themes.github.io/architect/), how would I do so? Essentially, is there a way for me to change the jekyll / kramdown markdown styling easily? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Docu - Default Values](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/) you see the item `markdown            : kramdown` inside `_config.yml`. Here you can change markdown renderer.

Some info can be found on the bottom of that [page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/)